# Firebase missing initial state on auth request

Tags: firebase, flutter, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use Apple sign-in with my Flutter/Firebase web app.  It works fine with a popup browser tab, so I know the general configuration is correct.  However, when the redirect flow is used instead of the popup, an error results.  When the Apple sign-in is complete, it makes a POST to Firebase's `https://YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler` URL which includes a `code` and `id_token`.  However, the Firebase Auth handler page gives the following error:

`Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared.`

Is there some configuration that I am missing to save the state in session storage before redirecting to the sign in page?  Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 5):

### Edit

To use Apple Sign In with Flutter apps it's required to implement a callback endpoint that redirects the user to the app with the sign in response. The Firebase callback is not supported. [See this doc](https://github.com/aboutyou/dart_packages/tree/master/packages/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple#server) for a guided step about how to implement such endpoint

---

### Original Answer

There is an open issue in `firebase-js-sdk` Github that addresses this issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4256. We probably need to await for a solution from Firebase team